# How to round this edge? Model is intended as a game asset

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: edge to round]

Hello blender gurus

I'm modelling this as an asset for UE. That's almost first "serious" model I'm making.. the problem I'm facing at the moment: can't understand how to
round the highlighted edges. Bevel doesn't help much.

An a Subsidiary question: is this topology very bad? It's full of ngons which I don't know how to get rid of now and should I start it all over again? (Hope not)

Thank a lot

Comment: If you are going to use the model "as is", i.e. no subsurf or beveling etc. then I *think* this topology might work. If you are planning to subsurf it to get smooth edges or something then most likely you'll need to change the geometry. As for edge - it should be beveled. The reason it didn't work probably is because it created black artifacts of wrongly shaded ngons.

Comment: Bevel probably doesn't work because you have ngons in your geometry. Ngongs are bad not only for game assets. You might want to upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for further inspection  and then post the given link into your question.

Answer (score 3):

For a game asset unfortunately yes, it sounds like you have a bad topology, it's very NGon heavy, and should ideally be mostly quad based.

You don't necessarily have to start over from scratch, although cleaning up bad topology from a model is often more work than just doing it well from the start.

I'd go with a topology roughly like this, which should bevel well without unexpected results

[image]

Comment: Thank you  for the answer, I have remodelled as a result :)