# What techniques are the best to make a gradually curved surface for the side of a model train? (photo attached)

Tags: 3d-printing

I would like some advice before I start a new build. I am trying to work out the best way of gradually curving the sides of a train as per the image below. The sides (on most trains these are typically flat) are slightly curved and feature windows inset into them which I will need to model. I was wondering what the best way to achieve this would be in Blender? Would a bevel work and if so then are there any tips that could help as I have found that beveling things to get coplicated if there are a significant number of curved surfaces.

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Thanks

[image: Train with curved sides]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64589/how-to-round-this-edge-model-is-intended-as-a-game-asset also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/adding-edge-loops-around-airplane-window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would not use a modifier to do this, but block it out low poly at first.

This was created (very fast) using extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, creating loop cuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then beveling these cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (using the mouse wheel to control the amount of bevel).

Windows are created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to insert faces, then <kbd>F3</kbd> to repeat the same insert amount for all the windows.

[image]

the side curve are created with a single loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and scaled on the width and beveled it out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to get the rounding.

[image]

Comment: Please use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> markup for writing keyboard keys.